# How to flatten a list to a list without coercion?

Tags: list, r, standard-library, flatten, type-coercion

I am trying to achieve the functionality similar to unlist, with the exception that types are not coerced to a vector, but the list with preserved types is returned instead. For instance:

```
flatten(list(NA, list("TRUE", list(FALSE), 0L))
```

should return

```
list(NA, "TRUE", FALSE, 0L)
```

instead of

```
c(NA, "TRUE", "FALSE", "0")
```

which would be returned by `unlist(list(list(NA, list("TRUE", list(FALSE), 0L))`.

As it is seen from the example above, the flattening should be recursive. Is there a function in standard R library which achieves this, or at least some other function which can be used to easily and efficiently implement this?

**UPDATE**: I don't know if it is clear from the above, but non-lists should not be flattened, i.e. `flatten(list(1:3, list(4, 5)))` should return `list(c(1, 2, 3), 4, 5)`.

Comment: What should `flatten( list(1:3, list(1:3, 'foo')) )` return?

Comment: `list(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 3), 'foo')`. Explanation: `1:3` is not a list, so it should not be flatten.

Comment: `purrr::flatten` looks like current best practice (as per @Aurèle's answer)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Interesting non-trivial problem!

**MAJOR UPDATE** With all that's happened, I've rewrote the answer and removed some dead ends. I also timed the various solutions on different cases.

Here's the first, rather simple but slow, solution:

```
flatten1 <- function(x) {
  y <- list()
  rapply(x, function(x) y <<- c(y,x))
  y
}
```

`rapply` lets you traverse a list and apply a function on each leaf element. Unfortunately, it works exactly as `unlist` with the returned values. So I ignore the result from `rapply` and instead I append values to the variable `y` by doing `<<-`.

Growing `y` in this manner is not very efficient (it's quadratic in time). So if there are many thousands of elements this will be very slow.

A more efficient approach is the following, with simplifications from @JoshuaUlrich:

```
flatten2 <- function(x) {
  len <- sum(rapply(x, function(x) 1L))
  y <- vector('list', len)
  i <- 0L
  rapply(x, function(x) { i <<- i+1L; y[[i]] <<- x })
  y
}
```

Here I first find out the result length and pre-allocate the vector. Then I fill in the values.
As you can will see, this solution is *much* faster.

Here's a version of @JoshO'Brien great solution based on `Reduce`, but extended so it handles arbitrary depth:

```
flatten3 <- function(x) {
  repeat {
    if(!any(vapply(x, is.list, logical(1)))) return(x)
    x <- Reduce(c, x)
  }
}
```

Now let the battle begin!

```
# Check correctness on original problem 
x <- list(NA, list("TRUE", list(FALSE), 0L))
dput( flatten1(x) )
#list(NA, "TRUE", FALSE, 0L)
dput( flatten2(x) )
#list(NA, "TRUE", FALSE, 0L)
dput( flatten3(x) )
#list(NA_character_, "TRUE", FALSE, 0L)

# Time on a huge flat list
x <- as.list(1:1e5)
#system.time( flatten1(x) )  # Long time
system.time( flatten2(x) )  # 0.39 secs
system.time( flatten3(x) )  # 0.04 secs

# Time on a huge deep list
x <-'leaf'; for(i in 1:11) { x <- list(left=x, right=x, value=i) }
#system.time( flatten1(x) ) # Long time
system.time( flatten2(x) )  # 0.05 secs
system.time( flatten3(x) )  # 1.28 secs
```

...So what we observe is that the `Reduce` solution is faster when the depth is low, and the `rapply` solution is faster when the depth is large!

As correctness goes, here are some tests:

```
> dput(flatten1( list(1:3, list(1:3, 'foo')) ))
list(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, "foo")
> dput(flatten2( list(1:3, list(1:3, 'foo')) ))
list(1:3, 1:3, "foo")
> dput(flatten3( list(1:3, list(1:3, 'foo')) ))
list(1L, 2L, 3L, 1:3, "foo")
```

Unclear what result is desired, but I lean towards the result from `flatten2`...

Comment: I came up with something similar to your update, but perhaps less complicated: `y <- vector("list", sum(rapply(x,length))); i <- 1` then `rapply(x, function(z) {y[[i]] <<- z; i <<- i+1})`.  It's about as fast as your updated solution.

Comment: Silly me, yes, that's much easier - I didn't think `y[[i]] <<- z` would work so I didn't even try it!

Comment: @Tommy -- I just stole your most recent version of flatten, adding a line that takes care of the corner case you identified.  Hope you don't mind, and feel free to edit your own version accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: +1 -- Don't know how I didn't already upvote this post.  This should put you up top so that your excellent comparisons get max visibility.  Plus, I definitely prefer the output of `flatten2`.

Comment: Thanks. You can eliminate flatten1. Not only it is the slowest one, but it also doesn't preserve non-lists (i.e. 1:5 flattens while it should not).

Comment: @Tommy: can you come up with a solution that preserves names in a named list?

Comment: One problem with most of these methods is that `NULL` elements silently get dropped.

Comment: @Tommy, sorry for the previous missing of attribution in my package function `rlist::list.flatten` for using your implementation of flatten2. You deserve full credit of it at https://github.com/renkun-ken/rlist/blob/master/R/list.flatten.R and thanks for your idea!

Answer (score 14):

For lists that are only a few nestings deep, you could use `Reduce()` and `c()` to do something like the following.  Each application of `c()` removes one level of nesting. **(For fully general solution, see EDITs below.)**

```
L <- (list(NA, list("TRUE", list(FALSE), 0L)))
Reduce(c, Reduce(c, L))
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] "TRUE"

[[3]]
[1] FALSE

[[4]]
[1] 0



# TIMING TEST
x <- as.list(1:4e3)
system.time(flatten(x))   # Using the improved version    
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.14    0.00    0.13 
system.time(Reduce(c, x))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.04    0.00    0.03
```

**EDIT** Just for fun, here's a version of @Tommy's version of @JoshO'Brien's solution that **does work** for already flat lists. **FURTHER EDIT** Now @Tommy's solved that problem as well, but in a cleaner way. I'll leave this version in place.

```
flatten <- function(x) {
    x <- list(x)
    repeat {
        x <- Reduce(c, x)
        if(!any(vapply(x, is.list, logical(1)))) return(x)
    }
}

flatten(list(3, TRUE, 'foo'))
# [[1]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] TRUE
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "foo"
```

Comment: +1 for nice use of `Reduce`! ...But it doesn't seem to handle `flatten(list(3, TRUE, 'foo'))`

Comment: I am more concerned about implementing it recursively, in order to wor for non constant depth lists. Is there a function which can be used to detect if a list is flattened?

Comment: @leden -- You can test whether a list is flat with `!any(sapply(L, class)=="list")`, which will evaluate to `TRUE` for fully flattened lists.

Comment: @leden - I added a variant that does that.

Comment: @Tommy -- Why'd you have to go ahead and ruin a perfectly elegant solution ;).  If the function might be passed already flat lists, you'd need to either: (a) check for that case in advance; or (b) pre-emptively wrap every list passed to it, like this: `Reduce(c, list(x))`, where in your example, `x <- list(3, TRUE, 'foo')`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - well, I got you to post a better solution, didn't I? ;-). A suggestion: just move the `if` clause before `Reduce` and skip the `x<-list(x)`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien wouldn't `!any(vapply(L, is.list, logical(1)))` be better?

Comment: @hadley -- You're referring to the comment four comments up from yours, where I suggested `!any(sapply...` right?  (In the body of the post, I did use the better idiom that you (and Tommy) suggested).

Comment: @ttmaccer -- Great catch. I'd wager good money that the `Reduce()` formulation will **never** be faster than your `do.call()` construct, and it'll sometimes be MUCH slower. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

How about this?  It builds off Josh O'Brien's solution but does the recursion with a `while` loop instead using `unlist` with `recursive=FALSE`.

```
flatten4 <- function(x) {
  while(any(vapply(x, is.list, logical(1)))) { 
    # this next line gives behavior like Tommy's answer; 
    # removing it gives behavior like Josh's
    x <- lapply(x, function(x) if(is.list(x)) x else list(x))
    x <- unlist(x, recursive=FALSE) 
  }
  x
}
```

Keeping the commented line in gives results like this (which Tommy prefers, and so do I, for that matter).

```
> x <- list(1:3, list(1:3, 'foo'))
> dput(flatten4(x))
list(1:3, 1:3, "foo")
```

Output from my system, using Tommy's tests:

```
dput(flatten4(foo))
#list(NA, "TRUE", FALSE, 0L)

# Time on a long 
x <- as.list(1:1e5)
system.time( x2 <- flatten2(x) )  # 0.48 secs
system.time( x3 <- flatten3(x) )  # 0.07 secs
system.time( x4 <- flatten4(x) )  # 0.07 secs
identical(x2, x4) # TRUE
identical(x3, x4) # TRUE

# Time on a huge deep list
x <-'leaf'; for(i in 1:11) { x <- list(left=x, right=x, value=i) }
system.time( x2 <- flatten2(x) )  # 0.05 secs
system.time( x3 <- flatten3(x) )  # 1.45 secs
system.time( x4 <- flatten4(x) )  # 0.03 secs
identical(x2, unname(x4)) # TRUE
identical(unname(x3), unname(x4)) # TRUE
```

EDIT: As for getting the depth of a list, maybe something like this would work; it gets the index for each element recursively.

```
depth <- function(x) {
  foo <- function(x, i=NULL) {
    if(is.list(x)) { lapply(seq_along(x), function(xi) foo(x[[xi]], c(i,xi))) }
    else { i }
  }
  flatten4(foo(x))
}
```

It's not super fast but it seems to work fine.

```
x <- as.list(1:1e5)
system.time(d <- depth(x)) # 0.327 s

x <-'leaf'; for(i in 1:11) { x <- list(left=x, right=x, value=i) }
system.time(d <- depth(x)) # 0.041s
```

I'd imagined it being used this way:

```
> x[[ d[[5]] ]]
[1] "leaf"
> x[[ d[[6]] ]]
[1] 1
```

But you could also get a count of how many nodes are at each depth too.

```
> table(sapply(d, length))

   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11 
   1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256  512 3072
```

Comment: +1 for continuing to extend this.  Now if only we had some way to quickly assess the depth of lists...  Any ideas?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: See edit for depth idea.  It works but it's not great.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Aaron. Nice solution, but I agree it's not ideal. It would be nice to find something that always ran faster than the worst case `flatten4` timings.  My two thoughts are: "I wonder if the phylogenetics folks already have something like this in a package", and "Folks who work with parsers could do this in a snap".

Comment: I played for a few minutes with the string resulting from `deparse(L)`, i.e. `"list(NA, list(\"TRUE\", list(FALSE), 0L))"`, but realized I'm in over my head/don't have the time. My basic idea was to run through it once, counting every occurrence of the substring `list(` as a `+1`, and every matching right paren `)` as a `-1`.  `max(cumsum())` or some equivalent would get you the maximum depth.  Seems like a sound approach with a perhaps monstrous regexp needed for the implementation! This might be a good SO question for one of us to ask at some point...

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the best solution so far.

Comment: +1. This solves another problem: the other functions unlist vectors as well, this one only lists. (Tommy's solution does **not** do this when vectors and lists are in depth=2)

Comment: if you change both instances of `is.list` in `flatten4` to `function(x) !is.data.frame(x) & is.list(x)`, then this will work for data frames as well which none of the answers currently do `flatten4(list(1:3, list(1:3, 'foo'), TRUE, 'hi', list(head(mtcars), list(tail(mtcars)))))` works like a dream

Answer (score 5):

*Edited to address a flaw pointed out in the comments. Sadly, it just makes it even less efficient. Ah well.*

Another approach, although I'm not sure it will be more efficient than anything @Tommy has suggested:

```
l <- list(NA, list("TRUE", list(FALSE), 0L))

flatten <- function(x){
    obj <- rapply(x,identity,how = "unlist")
    cl <- rapply(x,class,how = "unlist")
    len <- rapply(x,length,how = "unlist")
    cl <- rep(cl,times = len)
    mapply(function(obj,cl){rs <- as(obj,cl); rs}, obj, cl, 
        SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}

> flatten(l)
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] "TRUE"

[[3]]
[1] FALSE

[[4]]
[1] 0
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit (~3x) slower, but +1 for interesting solution!

Comment: Hmm. I fails for `flatten( list(1:3, list(1:3, 'foo')) )`

Comment: @Tommy Good catch. I edited to address the problem, although it will make the performance even worse that before, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

`purrr::flatten` achieves that. Though it is not recursive (by design).

So applying it twice should work:

```
library(purrr)
l <- list(NA, list("TRUE", list(FALSE), 0L))
flatten(flatten(l))
```

Here is an attempt at a recursive version:

```
flatten_recursive <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(is.list(x))
  if (any(vapply(x, is.list, logical(1)))) Recall(purrr::flatten(x)) else x
}
flatten_recursive(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hack_list <- function(.list) {
  .list[['_hack']] <- function() NULL
  .list <- unlist(.list)
  .list$`_hack` <- NULL
  .list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (extended version of base-`rapply`) by setting `how = "flatten"`:

```r
library(rrapply)

rrapply(list(NA, list("TRUE", list(FALSE), 0L)), how = "flatten")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "TRUE"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 0
```

**Computation times**

Below are some benchmark timings against the `flatten2` and `flatten3` functions in Tommy's response for two large nested lists:

```r
flatten2 <- function(x) {
  len <- sum(rapply(x, function(x) 1L))
  y <- vector('list', len)
  i <- 0L
  rapply(x, function(x) { i <<- i+1L; y[[i]] <<- x })
  y
}

flatten3 <- function(x) {
  repeat {
    if(!any(vapply(x, is.list, logical(1)))) return(x)
    x <- Reduce(c, x)
  }
}

## large deeply nested list (1E6 elements, 6 layers)
deep_list <- rrapply(replicate(10, 1, simplify = F), classes = c("list", "numeric"), condition = function(x, .xpos) length(.xpos) < 6, f = function(x) replicate(10, 1, simplify = F), how = "recurse")

system.time(flatten2(deep_list))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   1.715   0.012   1.727
## system.time(flatten3(deep_list)), not run takes more than 10 minutes
system.time(rrapply(deep_list, how = "flatten"))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.105   0.016   0.121

## large shallow nested list (1E6 elements, 2 layers)
shallow_list <- lapply(replicate(1000, 1, simplify = F), function(x) replicate(1000, 1, simplify = F))

system.time(flatten2(shallow_list))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   1.308   0.040   1.348
system.time(flatten3(shallow_list))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   5.246   0.012   5.259
system.time(rrapply(shallow_list, how = "flatten"))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.09    0.00    0.09
```