# Recursive eval in the global environment

Tags: r

I am having a hard time understanding why my attempt to recursively apply `eval`, using `rapply`, is not working.

I have a nested list of expressions:

```
# Some expressions   
expr1 <- quote(x <- x + 9)
expr2 <- quote(x <- x/2)
expr3 <- quote(x <- x + 3)
expr4 <- quote(x <- x * 3)

# Generate a nested list of expressions
exprs <- list(expr1, list(expr2, expr3), expr4)

# Initialize x, and attempt to eval the expressions
x <- 1
rapply(exprs, eval, envir = globalenv())
# Returns: [1] 10  5  8 24, but x is not changed.
```

Clearly the recursion worked, but it did not evaluate the expression in the global environment, like I specified. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8139959/1623354) I flattened out the list, and can `eval` using `lapply`.

```
flatten <- function(x) {
  repeat {
    if(!any(vapply(x, is.list, logical(1)))) return(x)
    x <- Reduce(c, x)
  }
}

# Both change x to 24 in the global env, like desired.
lapply(flatten(exprs), eval, envir = globalenv())
lapply(flatten(exprs), eval, envir = parent.frame())
```

As far as I understand `rapply`/`lapply` evaluate in their own environment, just like any other function, then return a value. It makes sense that I can specify the global environment, or the parent frame (because the parent frame of `lapply` should be the environment it was called in - here the global environment.)

Following this logic I would expect specifying the global environment with `rapply` to work. Specifying the parent frame should fail (and it does), because I am assuming the calls nested one deep within `rapply` get evaluated in the environment created by the original call to `rapply`.

What am I missing here? Why doesn't the `rapply` call change `x` in the global environment?

Comment: Note that you really should be using `quote()` here, not `bquote()`

Comment: @hadley Agreed. In my actual code I have a list of functions that generate data.table expressions using `bquote()`, ie. `bquote(dat[.(ids), dosomething])`, and I am trying to figure out the best way to evaluate the nested lists of expression objects. I have also looked at using your `as.quoted()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note from documentation for `rapply`:

> The semantics differ in detail from lapply: in particular the **arguments are evaluated before calling the C code**.

Try the following to see what they mean:

```
rapply(list(quote(stop("error"))), function(x) x)
# Error in (function (x)  : error
lapply(list(quote(stop("error"))), function(x) x)
# [[1]]
# stop("error")
```

You can try this as a workaround:

```
rapply(exprs, evalq, envir = globalenv())  # updated with Hadley's equivalent but cleaner version.
# [1] 10  5  8 24
x
# [1] 24
```

As you noted, `x` is getting evaluated in the `rapply` environment, which is why the result makes sense, but the actual `eval` statement is not of your original expression, but of the result (i.e. in the first iteration, `10` gets evaluated in the global env, not `x <- x + 9`).  By using `substitute` we're able to salvage the original expression.

Comment: Or `rapply(exprs, evalq, envir = globalenv())`

Comment: Also it's not clear what evaluated means in this case. I suspect the behaviour of `rapply()` is a bug

Comment: @hadley & BrodieG, if you're interested this solution is no longer working in R-3.2. I have asked a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31416347/1623354.