# Processing arbitrary hierarchies recursively with purrr

Tags: r, recursion, purrr, tidyverse

Suppose that I wanted to prune a tree consisting of a hierarchy of nested lists in R, based on some particular criterion. I can do this "easily" enough using `lapply`:

```
# Based an example from the NetworkD3 documentation
# https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/

URL <- paste0(
  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
  "master/JSONdata//flare.json")

flare <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)

# Leaf nodes have a "size" attribute. Let's say we want to 
# prune all the nodes with size < 5000.

prune <- function(tree) {
  if ("children" %in% names(tree)) {
    p <- lapply(tree$children, prune)
    pp <- p[!unlist(lapply(p, is.null))]
    copied_tree = list()
    copied_tree$name = tree$name
    copied_tree$children = pp
    return(copied_tree)
  } else if (tree$size < 5000) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  return(tree)
}

pruned <- prune(flare)
```

In *R for Data Science*, Hadley Wickham [discusses](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/lists.html) a number of scenarios in which `purrr` can replace the `apply` family of functions for handling hierarchical data. However, these examples seem to deal either with singly nested lists, or with specific nodes of deeply nested lists.

Is there a way to use `purrr` to accomplish recursive tasks such as the one discussed above?

Comment: Maybe this previous attempt of mine is relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/a/39869503/6197649

Comment: The issue is that I want to preserve the tree structure, except for pruning. I thought of creating a delimited node path (like xpath), then flattening, and finally reconstructing the hierarchy, but this seemed harder and more inelegant than just using lapply.

Comment: `purrr::map` is a drop-in replacement for `lapply` (with some extras), but it won't really change what you're doing here. You might check out `rapply`, which _is_ recursive, but which can be a little finicky to get to work right.

Comment: @alistaire is right, and my answer does address the `purrr` part of the question, not the 'recursive' part indeed. I think this is by design that `purrr` lacks such a recursive feature, because of "safety" concerns

Comment: See https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/01/06/purrr-0-2-0/ where Hadley says: "Base R has unlist(), but it’s dangerous because it always succeeds". I think it applies to `rapply()` as well. I'll see if I can think of a `rapply()` solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(purrr)
prune_2 <- function(tree) {
  # print(tree$name)
  # print(map_lgl(tree$children, ~ "size" %in% names(.x)))
  tree$children %<>%  
    map_if(~ "children" %in% names(.x), prune_2) %>% 
    discard(~ if ("size" %in% names(.x)) .x$size < 5000 else FALSE)
  tree
}
pruned_2 <- prune_2(flare)
identical(pruned, pruned_2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is very elegant (and impressive)! Can you tell me what the tilde does here? I'm fuzzy on how this symbol is used--I know it's used in statistical models and ggplot facets, but I don't know how it's interpreted by R.

Comment: Thank you. The tilde is for formulas that are a versatile syntax in R. Here they are used as a shortcut for anonymous functions, with `.x` and `.y` as implicit arguments. See `purrr` README or `help(map)` for instance: `~ .x + 1` is equivalent to `function(.x) .x + 1`