# Recursive indexing of lists with variable index value per recursion step

Tags: r, recursion, indexing, purrr

Puh... even trying to frame the title properly already gives me a headache.

I have a `config.yml` with **nested** values and I would like to define an indexing function `get_config()` that accepts "path-like" value strings.

The "path entities" of the value string match the nested entity structure of the config file. Based on the path-like value the function should then go and grab the corresponding hierarchy entity (either "branches" or "leaves") from the config file.

### Example

Suppose this is the structure of the `config.yml`:

```
default:
  column_names:
    col_id: "id"
    col_value: "value"
  column_orders:
    data_structure_a: [
      column_names/col_id,
      column_names/col_value
    ]
    data_structure_b: [
      column_names/col_value,
      column_names/col_id
    ]
```

Here's a parsed version for you to play around with:

```
x <- yaml::yaml.load(
'default:
  column_names:
    col_id: "id"
    col_value: "value"
  column_orders:
    data_structure_a: [
      column_names/col_id,
      column_names/col_value
    ]
    data_structure_b: [
      column_names/col_value,
      column_names/col_id
    ]'
)
```

Accessing top-level entities is easy with `config::get(value)`:

```
config::get("column_names")
# $col_id
# [1] "id"
# 
# $col_value
# [1] "value"

config::get("column_orders")
# [1] "hello" "world"
```

But I would also like to access deeper entities, e.g. `column_names: col_id`.

In pseudo code:

```
config::get("column_names:col_id")
```

or

```
config::get("column_orders/data_structure_a")
```

### The best I could come up with so far: relying on `unlist()`

```
get_config <- function(value, sep = ":") {
  if (value %>% stringr::str_detect(sep)) {
    value <- value %>% stringr::str_replace(sep, ".")
    configs <- config::get() %>% unlist()
    configs[value]
  } else {
    config::get(value)
  }
}

get_config("column_names")
# $col_id
# [1] "id"
#
# $col_value
# [1] "value"

get_config("column_names:col_id")
# column_names.col_id 
# "id"
```

Though not elegant, it works for most use cases, but fails for unnamed list entities in the config file

```
get_config("column_orders:data_structure_a")
# <NA> 
#   NA
```

as my indexing approach doesn't play well with the result of `unlist()` on unnamed lists:

```
config::get() %>% unlist()
# column_names.col_id          column_names.col_value 
# "id"                         "value" 
# column_orders.data_structure_a1 column_orders.data_structure_a2 
# "column_names/col_id"        "column_names/col_value" 
# column_orders.data_structure_b1 column_orders.data_structure_b2 
# "column_names/col_value"           "column_names/col_id"
```

Thus, I'd like to "go recursive" but my brain says: "no way, dude"

### Due diligence

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573995/processing-arbitrary-hierarchies-recursively-with-purrr) comes close (I guess).

But I keep thinking that I need something like `purrr::map2_if()` or `purrr::pmap_if()` (which AFAIK don't exist) instead of `purrr::map_if()`, as I need to not only traverse the list behind `config::get()` recursively, but also a  listified version of `value` (e.g. via `stringr::str_split(value, sep) %>% unlist() %>% as.list()`)?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `purrr::pluck` to index into a nested list by name if that is what you are after:

```r
x <- yaml::yaml.load('
  column_names:
    col_id: "id"
    col_value: "value"
  column_orders:
    data_structure_a: [
      column_names/col_id,
      column_names/col_value
    ]
    data_structure_b: [
      column_names/col_value,
      column_names/col_id
    ]
  nested_list:
    element_1:
      element_2:
        value: "hello world"
  ')

purrr::pluck(x, "column_names", "col_id")
#> [1] "id"

purrr::pluck(x, "column_names")
#> $col_id
#> [1] "id"
#> 
#> $col_value
#> [1] "value"

purrr::pluck(x, "column_orders", "data_structure_a")
#> [1] "column_names/col_id"    "column_names/col_value"

purrr::pluck(x, "column_names", "col_notthere")
#> NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution based on `Recall()`.

However, while digging up the internet in trying to get here, I recall having read somewhere that `Recall()` is generally not a very (memory) efficient way of doing recursion in R? Also would appreciate additional hints on how to do recursion the tidy way with `purrr` and friends.

### Config file content

Being able to call `get_config()` implies that you have a `config.yml` file with above content in your project's root directory given by `here::here()`, but you can test `get_list_element_recursively()` with this workaround:

```
x <- yaml::yaml.load('
  column_names:
    col_id: "id"
    col_value: "value"
  column_orders:
    data_structure_a: [
      column_names/col_id,
      column_names/col_value
    ]
    data_structure_b: [
      column_names/col_value,
      column_names/col_id
    ]
  nested_list:
    element_1:
      element_2:
        value: "hello world"
  ')
```

### Function defs

```
get_config <- function(value, sep = "/") {
  get_list_element_recursively(
    config::get(),
    stringr::str_split(value, sep, simplify = TRUE)
  )
}

get_list_element_recursively <- function(
  lst,
  el,
  .el_trace = el,
  .level_trace = 1
) {
  # Reached leaf:
  if (!is.list(lst)) {
    return(lst)
  }

  # Element not in list:
  if (!(el[1] %in% names(lst))) {
    message("Current list branch:")
    # print(lst)
    message(str(lst))
    message("Trace of indexing vec (last element is invalid):")
    message(stringr::str_c(.el_trace[.level_trace], collapse = "/"))
    stop(stringr::str_glue("No such element in list: {el[1]}"))
  }

  lst <- lst[[ el[1] ]]

  if (!is.na(el[2])) {
    # Continue if there are additional elements in `el` vec
    Recall(lst, el[-1], .el_trace, .level_trace = 1:(.level_trace + 1))
  } else {
    # Otherwise return last indexing result:
    lst
  }
}
```

### Testing `get_config()`

```
get_config("column_names")
# $col_id
# [1] "id"
#
# $col_value
# [1] "value"

get_config("column_names/col_id")
# [1] "id"

get_config("column_names/col_nonexisting")
# Current list branch:
#   List of 6
# $ col_id                    : chr "id"
# $ col_value                 : chr "value"
#
# Trace of indexing vec (last element is invalid):
#   column_names/col_nonexisting
# Error in get_list_element_recursively(config::get(), stringr::str_split(value,  :
#     No such element in list: col_nonexisting

get_config("column_orders")
# $data_structure_a
# [1] "column_names/col_id"    "column_names/col_value"
#
# $data_structure_b
# [1] "column_names/col_value" "column_names/col_id"

get_config("column_orders/data_structure_a")
# [1] "column_names/col_id"    "column_names/col_value"
```

### Testing `get_list_element_recursively()`

```
get_list_element_recursively(x, c("column_names"))
# $col_id
# [1] "id"
#
# $col_value
# [1] "value"

get_list_element_recursively(x, c("column_names", "col_id"))
# [1] "id"

get_list_element_recursively(x, c("column_names", "col_notthere"))
# Current list branch:
#   List of 2
# $ col_id   : chr "id"
# $ col_value: chr "value"
#
# Trace of indexing vec (last element is invalid):
#   column_names/col_notthere
# Error in get_list_element_recursively(x$default, c("column_names", "col_notthere")) :
#   No such element in list: col_notthere
```